# iOS CoreBluetooth unlikely error

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on an Appcelerator module that utilizes Core Bluetooth. I can connect to a peripheral without issue, and subscribe to a characteristic. I have implimented all delegate functions and everything appears to be firing as expected, except that I get an 'unlikely error' when attempting to read or write. My central methods are shown below.

```
-(void)readValueForCharacteristicByUUID:(NSString *)uuidstring
{
if (self.connectedService)
{
    CBMutableCharacteristic* characteristic = [self characteristicFromUUIDstring:uuidstring];
    if (characteristic)
    {
        [self.connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"[INFO] No service to read");
}
}

-(void)writeValue:(NSData*)value ForCharacteristicByUUID:(NSString*)uuidstring
{
if (self.connectedService)
{
    CBMutableCharacteristic* characteristic = [self characteristicFromUUIDstring:uuidstring];
    if (characteristic)
    {
        [self.connectedPeripheral writeValue:value forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"[INFO] No service to write to");
}
}

-(CBMutableCharacteristic*)characteristicFromUUIDstring:(NSString*)uuidstring
{
for (CBMutableCharacteristic* c in self.connectedService.characteristics)
{
    if ([c.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:uuidstring])
    {
        return c;
    }
}
NSLog(@"No Characteristic found with that uuid");
}
```

I am thinking it may be a permissions issue, so here is the code I use to create the characteristics in my peripheral.

```
CBMutableCharacteristic* c = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:cuuid
                                                                properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead|CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite|
                                                                    CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                                                     value:nil
                                                               permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable|CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`CBMutableCharacteristic class reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic_Class/index.html)

> CBMutableCharacteristic objects represent the characteristics of a
>   local peripheral’s service (local peripheral devices are represented
>   by CBPeripheralManager objects).

You can't use a `CBMutableCharacteristic` instance with a `CBCentralManager` to communicate with a remote peripheral.

You have to use the `CBCharacteristic` that is returned to the peripheral's `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:` delegate method after calling `discoverCharacteristics:forService:` on the connected `CBPeripheral`.

Comment: Clarification for those new to CoreBluetooth: Contrary to the wording of this answer, there is no CBCharacteristic returned to the delegate method directly. The delegate is simply a notification that new characteristics were discovered. You need to scan the service (passed to the aforementioned delegate) for any new characteristics. They will appear in the 'characteristics' property of CBService object. Depending on your implementation, this may require storing a list of known characteristics so new ones can be recognized upon discovery.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer in my case. I am storing the CBCharacteristic returned as suggested and use them for my read/write operations. I get no error on the reads. I get "value write error: Unlikely error" sent to the `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` method. I get this error every time regardless of the type (i.e., withResponse and withoutResponse). Also, I wrote the GATT server (BlueZ+D-Bus/Linux) and so I have full visibility to both sides and everything is working correctly. This feels like a spurious error in my case.

Comment: @pauln Have you solved this issue? I have exactly the same situation (gatt under linux written in python + ios swift app) and I stuck with this 'unlikely error'...

Comment: I did but unfortunately, I can't offer a concrete solution. In my case, the errors were only spurious and one day I noticed they had just weren't happening any longer. My git logs from that time offer one possibility, though: I fixed a bug that was exceeding the packet limit (which is only 20 bytes) by over a factor of 3. I wish I could offer more insight.

Comment: Update: I didn't solve it, but somebody else did. My case was pretty specific; a bug in the GATT server I was using. This GATT server was my own work which I later open-sourced. The bug had to do with my (mis)use of DBus. In case it helps, here's the link to the fix, which is only a line of code: https://github.com/nettlep/gobbledegook/pull/15/commits/2cfc676a76d566a1438923115dbaed3c2c691a78